Modify the graph construction to include the right type of edge (etype) in DGL edge classification example
DGL example throws error related to edge types. How do I modify the graph construction to include the right type of edge?
Starting with this example: Edge classification/Regression
Error I get:
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dgl/heterograph.py:2411, in DGLGraph.__getitem__(self, key)
   2408 etypes = self._find_etypes(key)
   2410 if len(etypes) == 0:
-> 2411     raise DGLError(
   2412         'Invalid key "{}". Must be one of the edge types.'.format(
   2413             orig_key
   2414         )
   2415     )
   2417 if len(etypes) == 1:
   2418     # no ambiguity: return the unitgraph itself
   2419     srctype, etype, dsttype = self._canonical_etypes[etypes[0]]

DGLError: Invalid key "0". Must be one of the edge types.

Code:
src = np.random.randint(0, 100, 500)
dst = np.random.randint(0, 100, 500)
# make it symmetric
edge_pred_graph = dgl.graph((np.concatenate([src, dst]), np.concatenate([dst, src])))

# synthetic node and edge features, as well as edge labels
edge_pred_graph.ndata['feature'] = torch.randn(100, 10)
edge_pred_graph.edata['feature'] = torch.randn(1000, 10)
edge_pred_graph.edata['label'] = torch.randn(1000)
# synthetic train-validation-test splits
edge_pred_graph.edata['train_mask'] = torch.zeros(1000, dtype=torch.bool).bernoulli(0.6)

<snip> 
    
node_features = edge_pred_graph.ndata['feature']
edge_label    = edge_pred_graph.edata['label']
train_mask    = edge_pred_graph.edata['train_mask']

model = Model(10, 20, 5)
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
for epoch in range(10):
    pred = model(edge_pred_graph, node_features)
    loss = ((pred[train_mask] - edge_label[train_mask]) ** 2).mean()
    opt.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    print(loss.item())

